# no profiling data created while compiling with gcc

Tags: gcc, gprof

I want to use the gprof profiling option in order to speed up my code. I am compiling with gcc. The problem is that there is not output file created 'gmon.out' or so. Here is a sample of the Makefile I am using:

```
CC =  gcc
LD = gcc
#LIBGSL = -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas
#LIBGSL = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
#LIBGSL = -L/home/dupont/gsl/gsl-2.4/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
LIBGSL = -L/n1/soft/64bit/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm

CFLAGSRELEASE = -g -fopenmp -O -Wall -c -pg -I/n1/hhsoft/64bit/include
LFLAGSRELEASE = -g -pg -lm -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib $(LIBGSL)

CFLAGSDEBUG = -g -p -pg  -Wall
LFLAGSDEBUG = -lm 

CFLAGSDEBUG = -g -p -pg -Wall -W    # -DDEBUG_OUTPUT
LFLAGSDEBUG =  -lm -p -pg -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib $(LIBGSL) 

LIBS= -L/home/dupont/folder/soft/pgplot -lm -lcpgplot /home/dupont/folder/soft/pgplot/libpgplot.a  -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11

CFLAGS = $(CFLAGSRELEASE)
LFLAGS = $(LFLAGSRELEASE)
```

I don't know much about makefile, do you have any idea of what the problem could be...?

Answer (score 1):

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.31/gprof/Executing.html

> Your program will write the profile data into a file called gmon.out just before exiting

So there's nothing wrong if make produces your program but not gmon.out.

(anyway, you should remove `-p`, and ensure you use `-pg` both for compilation and link).

Comment: Ok, this was just a problem with the '-p', now it is working, thanks!